# How to know which query is using given index in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-2012

I have figured out recently that one of my index is causing performance issue during the update query. Before removing this query I would like to know which all other Queries are using this index. I know we have way to identify how many times an index has been used, however that does not tell which all queries have used it.

Answer (score 1):

The index affects all queries which contain the indexed column. Indexes usually slow down `UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT` but on the other side should speed up `SELECT`.